# Flatlist not displaying anything on Android but works fine on iOS

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, flatlist

I got a Flatlist, that takes its data from an API through Axios, and it works perfectly fine on iOS simulator, however, on Android simulator it's just a blank screen. If I take away the Flatlist component and just display the Article object it works on Android but as I put back the Flatlist it won't show anything. As I said before, on iOS works fine.

The Flatlist itself:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import Article from '../components/Article';
import axios from 'axios';

const HomeScreen = () => {

    const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);


    const getNews = () => {

        // Make a request for a user with a given ID
        axios.get('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=65b529cf968b4b819070a4e078a109d3',{
                params: {
                    category:'sports'
                }
            })
        .then((response) => {
        // handle success
            setArticles(response.data.articles);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
        })
        .then(function () {
        // always executed
        });

    }

useEffect(()=>{
    getNews();
}, [])

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
            style={{ height: '100%', paddingBottom: 50 }}
            data = {articles}
            renderItem = {({item}) => 
                <Article
                    urlToImage = {item.urlToImage}
                    title = {item.title}
                    description = {item.description}
                    author = {item.author}
                    publishedAt = {item.publishedAt}
                    sourceName = {item.source.name}

                />}
            keyExtractor = {(item) => item.title} 
        />    
        
    </SafeAreaView>)  
        
}

export default HomeScreen

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {}
})
```

The Article object

```
import moment from 'moment'
import React from 'react'
import { SafeAreaView, View, Stylesheet, Image, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native'

const Article = (props) => {
    return (<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <Image 
        style={styles.image}
        source={{
            uri: props.urlToImage
        }}
        />
        <View style={{padding: 20}}>
            {/* Title */}
            <Text style={styles.title}>{props.title}</Text>

            {/* Desc */}
            <Text style={styles.description} numberOfLines={3}>{props.description}</Text>

            <View style={styles.data}>
                <Text style={styles.by}>Publicado por: <Text style={styles.author}>{props.author}</Text></Text>
                <Text style={styles.date}>{moment(props.publishedAt).format("MMM Do YY")}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style= {{marginTop:10}}>
                <Text style={styles.source}>Promoter: <Text style={styles.sourceLink}>{props.sourceName}</Text></Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    </SafeAreaView>)
}

export default Article

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        width: '90%',
        alignSelf: 'center',
        borderRadius: 40,
        shadowOpacity: 0.5,
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: {
            height: 5,
            width: 5
        },
        backgroundColor: '#FFF',
        marginTop: 20
    },
    image: {
        height: 200,
        width: "100%",
        borderTopLeftRadius: 40,
        borderTopRightRadius: 40
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: '600',
        marginTop: 10
    },
    description: {
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: '400',
        marginTop: 10
    },
    data: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        marginTop: 10
    },
    date: {
        color: '#38A3A5',
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    },
    author: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: '#38A3A5'
    },
    by: {
        fontWeight: '400'
    },
    source: {
        fontSize: 14,
        fontWeight: '400'
    },
    sourceLink: {
        fontSize: 14,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: '#38A3A5'
    }
})
```

And the call on the app's entry point

```
/**


* Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow strict-local
 */

import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';


import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen'

const App = () => {
  

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <HomeScreen/>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  }
})

export default App;
```

Comment: Your code is fine. Please try to re-run the app using `react-native run-android` or clear cache `react-native start --reset-cache`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try flex : 1 in container style in HomeScreen

```
...

export default HomeScreen

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: { flex : 1 }
})
```

check your code in expo: https://snack.expo.dev/@mainak-shil/d62881

Comment: It does work on Snack and devices, however I can't make it run on simulator, so it has to be some sim-related issue.